# CI: My_Controller not found when uploaded to webhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created an app via Code Igniter and everything works fine in xampp. But when I launch it on my webserver (Hawkhost), I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_controller' not found in /home/deremoec/public_html/an.deremoe/application/controllers/search.php on line 5
```

I already renamed the base_url from webhost to my domain.

I also renamed my .htaccess to the current webserver folder.

For a clear understanding

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://an.deremoe.com/';
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /an.deremoe/

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: did you check the case ?

Comment: the php file for My_controller class is MY_controller.php. Should I change it to my_controller.php? @zourite

Comment: What is the name of your class is identical to the filename? Yes try lowercase

Comment: Yes, they have the same MY_ as uppercase. Let me small all of them.

Comment: @zourite Tried renaming MY_controller.php to my_controller.php and MY_controller class to my_controller ... same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a problem with case sensitivity, just like  what zourite said. The problem here is that, you have to name the file `MY_Controller.php` and the class `MY_Controller`. Notice the uppercase "C".

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be accessing youre site with `http://an.deremoe.com/` in the browser. But youre using a RewriteBase that would put it at `http://whatever.com/an.deremoe/`.

Try changing your RewriteBase to `/`

Comment: Did you try it without a RewriteBase at all?

Comment: i think zourite has it nailed on the case sensitivity... so ill just bow out now... :-)